# Colorbox close button and title not showing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I can see that the title content is successfully read form the web browser and the close button settings in css are correct too as I can see the control.png file loaded using Inspect Element. 
I need the title and close button stay -20 px top of the float window. Tried to change the index of cboxOverlay, cboxTitle and cboxColose does not work.

BUT, I cannot see the title or the close button.
Here is part of my code:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //assign the Colorbox event to elements
            $(".feap2d").colorbox({
                inline: true,
                width: "700px"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="ap">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" valign="top" id="iP2D">
                <div class="productn">
                    <div class="vcompare">//Assign title to show as the title in Colorbox <a class="feap2d" href="#feap2d" title="test title">Version compare</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style='display:none'>//inline contents for element feap2d
        <div id='feap2d'>[
            <uc1:fP ID="fP" runat="server" />]</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I do not have enough reputations, so I cannot post an image to illustrator the issue.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8djT/9/embedded/result/)

Comment: create jsfiddle.net for this issue...so that we can see your issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v8djT/9/embedded/result/

Comment: updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/v8djT/19/embedded/result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your Css problem

just change cboxTitle css top peroperty to 0

```
top:0px;
```

same problem with your close button also

Comment: change top to 0px can show the title, but it does not fix the issue.
here is the example page, and you can see the title is above the float window. file:///C:/Users/Dodo.W/Desktop/colorbox-master/example2/index.html
Here is the updated jsfiddle.net result. http://jsfiddle.net/v8djT/11/embedded/result/
Also, the colose button still not shows.

Comment: image path in background  of close button is incorrect...and create your fiddle like this...http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/f32rk/1/

Comment: Here is the original example: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/     I need the title and close button show outside of the float window, that is -20px top of the window.     I do not know why the image for the close button not correct in the jsfiddle.net example, but here in my local page, it is corrected loaded in the browser.

Comment: try one more thing...just give the height also... in calling colorbox function

Comment: Add height not working too, it add more space to the bottom but will not show the title and close button. I tried to change index of the cboxOverlay, cboxTitle and cboxClose, but nothing changes. http://jsfiddle.net/v8djT/23/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks but I need the title and close button to stay -20px top of the window, just like the examples in this link: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/

Comment: make cboxContent css margin-top:32px as per your given example http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/ check this http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/v8djT/25/

Comment: Thank you so much. I tested the code for a whole day but you just solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough rep to voteup your answer. I'll try again when I have enough rep.

Comment: don't voteup.. just tick my reply as answer..that can be done by questionair